# Asp.net core 1.0 - Write javascript on Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to write a javascript result at Response.Body on MVC6/Asp.net core 1.0?

In my case, I want to render a script to call a notification for the client, and don´t want to put a code in my view to check wheter a new notification exists on ViewData (for exemple).

If I do this like:

```
   var bytesWrite = GetBytes(script);
   await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytesWrite, 0, bytesWrite.Length);
```

The result is the script rendered as HTML text.

**UPDATE:**

This might clear things out. I would like to return my View() as result. BUT, write on the Response.Body (obivious it will be encapsulated later) a `"<script> Alert("Hey")</script>"`

```
 public IActionResult Popup()
        {
            //logic
            //.....
            //var script = ProduceNotification();
            //

            //Render Notifications
            var bytesWrite = GetBytes(script);
            await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytesWrite, 0, bytesWrite.Length);

            //Return de view normally. It doesn´t know about any notifications beeing returned
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Did you try `return Content(xmlString, "application/javascript")` or `Produces("application/javascript")]` with ``return ObjectResult(string)`?

Comment: You should not write to the response Body and then return a view. Bodies are not intended to be composed this way. Pass the script into your view as text to be added to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve managed to do this with Components:

http://www.strathweb.com/2015/07/viewcomponents-asp-net-5-asp-net-mvc-6/
http://blog.2mas.xyz/asp-net-5-view-components/

The implementation steps are:

- Create a custom component that reads mesages stored on HttpContext.Items
- Create a View shared that others will inherit and on that view call you Component
- On the component return a view that only render the script calls